# How can one Rank Up without playing a competitive game?

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

I have recently played some DM and some of the players on the server were bragging about how they were Silver 2 without playing a single game of competitive. Is this possible and if yes then how is it achieved?

Comment: Down Vote please Explain?

Comment: It's a silly question, hence, you CAN'T rank up with out playing competitive mode. The rank is based on your competitive game play.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot rank up without playing competitive games, nor can you ever get a rank without playing a few competitive games.

From the [CS:GO Blog](http://blog.counter-strike.net/index.php/2012/10/5565/):

> Q. Where can I see my own Skill Group?
>
> A. Once your Skill Group has
>   settled and you have **won 10 competitive matches**, your Skill Group will
>   be displayed on the main menu.